# Suspend or hibernate from PowerShell

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I am interested in using Windows PowerShell to suspend or hibernate a computer. How do you achieve this?

I am already aware of the `Stop-Computer` and `Restart-Computer` cmdlets, which are included out of the box, but these do not achieve the functionality that I am after.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `SetSuspendState` method on the `System.Windows.Forms.Application` class to achieve this. The `SetSuspendState` method is a static method.

[[MSDN] SetSuspendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There are three parameters:

- State `[System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]`
- Force `[bool]`
- disableWakeEvent `[bool]`

To call the `SetSuspendState` method:

```
# 1. Define the power state you wish to set, from the
#    System.Windows.Forms.PowerState enumeration.
$PowerState = [System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend;

# 2. Choose whether or not to force the power state
$Force = $false;

# 3. Choose whether or not to disable wake capabilities
$DisableWake = $false;

# Set the power state
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState($PowerState, $Force, $DisableWake);
```

Putting this into a more complete function might look something like this:

```
function Set-PowerState {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
          [System.Windows.Forms.PowerState] $PowerState = [System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend
        , [switch] $DisableWake
        , [switch] $Force
    )

    begin {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Executing Begin block';

        if (!$DisableWake) { $DisableWake = $false; };
        if (!$Force) { $Force = $false; };

        Write-Verbose -Message ('Force is: {0}' -f $Force);
        Write-Verbose -Message ('DisableWake is: {0}' -f $DisableWake);
    }

    process {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Executing Process block';
        try {
            $Result = [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState($PowerState, $Force, $DisableWake);
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error -Exception $_;
        }
    }

    end {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Executing End block';
    }
}

# Call the function
Set-PowerState -PowerState Hibernate -DisableWake -Force;
```

Note: In my testing, the `-DisableWake` option did not make any distinguishable difference that I am aware of. I was still capable of using the keyboard and mouse to wake the computer, even when this parameter was set to `$true`.

Comment: About `disableWakeEvent`... This parameter can prevent `SetWaitableTimer()` to awake the computer. `SetWaitableTimer()` used by Task Scheduler (at least). See details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235.aspx

Comment: This didn't work for me on the console, I had to add `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` so it could find the requested classes.

Comment: Perfect. Works exactly the same way for `$PowerState = [System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Hibernate` on Windows 11, and requires the `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` as from the comment above. Thank you both!

Answer (score 31):

Hope you find these useful.

Shutdown `%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -s`

Reboot `%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -r`

Logoff `%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -l`

Standby `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby`

Hibernate `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate`

EDIT:
As pointed out in comment by @mica, the suspend (sleep) actually hibernates. Apparently this happens in windows 8 and above. To 'sleep', disable hibernation OR get an external Microsoft tool (not built-in)
"One of Microsoft's Sysinternals tool is PsShutdown using the command `psshutdown -d -t 0` it will correctly sleep, not hibernate, a computer"
Source: https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu

Comment: @Mica The answer is 3 years old. :P Just updated the answer

Comment: Since I already had AutoIt installed, I ended up using their shutdown cmdlet, where `Invoke-AU3Shutdown 32` is for standby. So that's another option.

Comment: Sysinternals is worth getting for psshutdown.exe alone, but the rest is pure win.

Comment: `shutdown.exe /h` is the easier way to hibernate.

Comment: `$Env:WinDir` is the powershell way.

Answer (score 20):

I use the shutdown executable in C:\Windows\System32

```
shutdown.exe /h
```

Comment: Following on from this,  you make a shortcut to shutdown.exe and then set the parameter to "/h" and the hotkey (I chose Ctrl+Alt+S) then you can hibernate with a keypress

Comment: I know this is old but the user specifically asked for a powershell command

Answer (score 6):

I tried reducing this down to a one-liner but was getting an error. Here's my solution:

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState("Hibernate", $false, $false);
```