# emergency shutdown windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I'm writing a small script to remotely shutdown all my servers in case of an emergency. Now is my question, is there a way to save all open files before it shutsdown so nothing is lost?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: Nooooooooooo. `;-)`

Comment: If it's a real emergency, then I guess it's similar to a fire where you need to _leave the building, not stopping to collect your belongings_ - if it's a real fire, you're stuff is gone.  As @gvee points out, there is no way to automatically save all work, so you need to decide which is worse: letting people save their stuff, but possibly allowing the 'emergency' play out, or killing everything immediately and losing unsaved data.

Comment: Alright thanks for the info.

Comment: There might be some middle ground by putting the machines in Hibernate state. See this question for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713782/suspend-or-hibernate-from-powershell